# Cordova Content Security Policy works on Android but fails on ios

Tags: ios, cordova, content-security-policy

My app has a functionality to upload images as string base64 to my Api.

I have the following CSP tag on my cordova app at the first line after `<head>` on Index.html

```
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * file: gap:; style-src * 'unsafe-inline'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; media-src * file: gap:; img-src * gap: data: mediastream: blob: filesystem:">
```

When I run on Android (emulator or device) my upload works fine, the HTTP Post request goes to the Api with all the data.

But when I try to run on iOS emulator all my Api calls that contains image fails. It calls the Api, but the request data is always NULL.

Am I missing something specific for iOS on my CSP tag?